# Error 1604 - Wrong Syntax MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Whenever I try to create and insert data into the created table (userid), the error code 1064 comes out (wrong syntax).

```
CREATE TABLE userid
(
LogIN int NOT NULL,
username varchar(40) NOT NULL,
pass varchar(40) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY LogIN,
);

INSERT INTO userid (username, pass)
VALUE (kimminseo, lukekms);
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: The error message would point you in the right direction.

Comment: logIn should be autoincrement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing quotes around your string values:

```
INSERT INTO userid (username, pass)
VALUE ('kimminseo', 'lukekms');
```

Comment: Thx, but I think there is another problem with the PRIMARY KEY LINE. Can you please help me look into it? thanks

Comment: @KimMinseo: Do you have some *indication* that there's another problem?  If you're getting an error, that error *probably* tells you what the problem is.

Comment: @JohnConde: There is only a red cross at that line

Comment: @KimMinseo You've got an extraneous comma at the end of `PRIMARY KEY LogIN,`, and you don't have a default value for your primary key, so your insert without setting a value will fail.