# PHP error 1604: accessing MySQL query and outputting it

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
require_once ('../include/ISS_consts.inc');
require_once ('../include/connect_to_db.inc');
require_once ('../include/utils.inc');
$query = "SELECT `first_name`, `last_name`, `mi`, `primary_phone` , `id`,`COUNT(*)` `FROM` `member_tbl` WHERE status = `ACTIVE` AND `primary_phone` <> `(000) 000-0000` GROUP BY first_name, last_name, primary_phone HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1";
try
{
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt = null;
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo "ERROR: ".$e->getMessage()."\n".$query."\n";
}

echo "This is the data".$query."\n";
?>
```

I have recently been learning php and I am trying to get data a query from MySQL but I keep getting a syntax error. I know I have one but I just don't know where and how many due to all the keywords I'm not sure of. I am also trying to figure out how to output the data or will the catch and try methods output it themselves, that is why I have an echo statement calling the query at the end.

Comment: Do not use backticks around non column names, EG `COUNT(*)` or `FROM`...

Comment: Also, the value of `primary_phone `, "(000) 000-0000", in the `WHERE` clause should use quotes not backticks.

Comment: Have you [tried the first hit when google'ing "mysql error 1604"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24658491/error-1604-wrong-syntax-mysql) ?

Answer (score 1):

remove backtics from FROM and count(*) and use quote for literal '(000) 000-0000' and 'ACTIVE'

```
    $query = "SELECT `first_name`, `last_name`, `mi`, `primary_phone` , `id`,COUNT(*) 
    FROM `member_tbl` 
    WHERE status = 'ACTIVE' AND `primary_phone` <> '(000) 000-0000' 
    GROUP BY first_name, last_name, primary_phone 
    HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1";
```

Comment: No backticks around active, either. Should be quoted.

Comment: @aynber  .. correct  .. answer  updated

Comment: You should have duped the question instead of answering @scaisEdge

Answer (score 0):

Backticks are used to quote column names and other user defined identifiers. Single quotes are used to enclose string constants.

Try something like this:

```
$query = "
SELECT `first_name`, `last_name`, `mi`, `primary_phone` , `id`, COUNT(*)
  FROM `member_tbl`
  WHERE status = 'ACTIVE' AND `primary_phone` <> '(000) 000-0000'
  GROUP BY first_name, last_name, primary_phone
  HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1";
```